# What does Naturals to the omega mean?

Tags: terminology

What is this called?

$$\mathbb{N}^\omega$$

Can't seem to find any mention of it when I google.

---

Context: comment to this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1384962/243059

Comment: It the set of all [succession of natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_space#Examples), i.e. the set of functions from $\omega$ to $\mathbb N$.

Comment: $\omega$ is the name of the first transfinite ordinal. It corresponds to $\mathbf N$.

Comment: IMO, there is a subtle difference: $\omega$ is an *ordinal*: thus it has an "order". $\mathbb N$ is a *set*: it has no order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, $A^B$ is the set of functions from $B\to A$. This makes sense with the usual set theoretic definition of natural numbers as the set of all natural numbers preceding it. So your example is the set of functions $\omega\to\mathbb N$, which are infinite sequences of natural numbers. If you consider $\omega$ and $\mathbb N$ to be the same thing, this is the same as $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

It is the set of infinite sequences of natural numbers.  $\Bbb N^2$ is the set of ordered pairs of naturals, $\Bbb N^3$ is the set of triplets, and $\Bbb N^\omega$ is the set of sequences of length $\omega$

Comment: And similarly $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ is the set of infinite real sequences?

Comment: Not sure how $\mathbb{N}^\omega$ is different from $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Yes, $\Bbb R^\omega$ is the set of (countably) infinite real sequences.  $N\Bbb ^N$ is the same as $N^\omega$.  Using $\omega$ emphasizes the point that the elements of the sequence are in order because $\omega$ is an ordinal.  You could think of $\Bbb {N^N}$ as generic functions from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$ without such emphasis on the fact that $\Bbb N$ is ordered.  It depends on the context.